# (Win Serv.) Служба долго запускается

Tags: c#, сокет, service, tcp, port

Я написал Windows-service, который слушает 25 порт на локальной машине.
Я установил службу и запускаю ее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Служба очень долго запускается, и в конце выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если зайти в эту службу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. ни остановить ни запустить ее нельзя, только удалить.

> Но при этом служба работает - пишет логи, порт слушает !

**Код проекта:**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    l.Write("Service started: " + ServiceName);
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Service started: " + ServiceName);

    try
    {
        SMTP s = new SMTP(this);
        s.Listen();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        l.Write("OnStart error: \n" + ex.ToString());
    }         
}
```

---

тут мы создаем сокет:

```
public void Listen()
{
    int iter = 0;

    try
    {
        SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        SMTP_Listener.Start();
        l.Write("SMTP started " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

        while (true)
        {
            l.Write("iteration: " + iter.ToString());

            clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();
            string sessionID = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();

            l.Write("New session: " + sessionID);

            StartProcessing();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        l.Write("SMTP Listen Error: " + ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}

void StartProcessing()
{
    l.Write("StartProcessing()  -  started");

    try
    {
        string m_ConnectedIp = ParseIP_from_EndPoint(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        string m_ConnectedHostName = GetHostName(m_ConnectedIp);

        l.Write(String.Format("m_ConnectedIp = {0}, m_ConnectedHostName = {1}", m_ConnectedIp, m_ConnectedHostName));

        //РАБОТА С ВХОДНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
        while (true)
        {
            //если есть данные, то считаем их
            if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                string lastCmd = ReadLine();
                l.Write("lastCmd: " + lastCmd);

                //break; // добавил

                //парсим команду
                ProceedCommand(lastCmd);
            }
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        l.Write("SMTP StartProcessing Error: " + ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }

    l.Write("StartProcessing()  -  end");
}
```

**Я хочу сделать так, чтобы служба могла нормально запускаться,  чтобы ее можно было нормально остановить из виндовс-интерфейса. Может все дело в бесконечных циклах ? Подскажите, пожалуйста.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш метод `Listen` никогда не возвращает управления - а чтобы система считала службу запущенной, надо вернуть управление из `OnStart`.

Вам нужно создать новый **поток** и слушать сокет в нем.

Comment: я должен переделать его через таймер?

Comment: @LeonardBertone где вы в моем ответе увидели слово "таймер"?

Comment: В справке МСДН я ранее читал что отдавать управление сервис должен с помощью таймера. Это еще можно как-то сделать?

Comment: @LeonardBertone либо вы читали глупость, либо неправильно поняли

Comment: @LeonardBertone что вам не понятно во фразе *"Вам нужно создать новый поток и слушать сокет в нем"*?

Comment: Я так и сделал - служба запускается/останавливается мгновенно, но команда  telnet localhost 25 выдает ошибку "Сбой подключения"

Comment: Я так сделал:  SMTP s = new SMTP(this);                  Thread listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Listen)); Все верно?

Comment: @LeonardBertone а запускать поток кто будет?

Comment: Спасибо, все работает